# how to implement pagination using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, php-7, php-5.5, php-5.6

I am trying to implement pagination using PHP and MySQL by using the following  code .

I have taken help from internet and changed the code but not able to get the value of page variable so code is not working effectively

Can you suggest me where is the error in the program or how can i get the page variable value. The program is just simple to implement the pagination using PHP and MYSQL db.
code is as following.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Paging Using PHP</title>
</head>

<body>
  <?php
     $dbhost = 'localhost';
     $dbuser = 'root';
     $dbpass = 'root123';

     $rec_limit = 10;
     $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

     if(! $conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }
     mysql_select_db('test_db');

     /* Get total number of records */
     $sql = "SELECT count(cinno) FROM register_data ";
     $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

     if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
     }
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
     $rec_count = $row[0];

     if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) ) {
        $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
        $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
     }else {
        $page = 0;
        $offset = 0;
     }

     $left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);
     $sql = "SELECT cinno ". 
        "FROM register_data ".
        "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

     $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

     if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "Cin No :{$row['cinno']}  <br> ";

     }

      echo "$page";
     if( $page > 0 ) {
        $last = $page - 2;
        echo "<a href = \"$_PHP_SELF?page = $last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
        echo "<a href = \"$_PHP_SELF?page = $page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
     }else if( $page == 0 ) {
        echo "<a href = \"$_PHP_SELF?page = $page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
     }else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit ) {
        $last = $page - 2;
        echo "<a href = \"$_PHP_SELF?page = $last\">Last 10 Records</a>";
     }

     mysql_close($conn);
    ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove the spaces in `page = $page` in your url. Someone else will probably tell you not to use mysql, but mysqli. Listen to them.

Comment: You've tagged the question with `php-5.5`, `php-5.6` and `php-7` tags, so please be aware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions you're using in your code are deprecated in 5.5 and 5.6, and were removed entirely from the language in PHP 7.0. You will need to learn about the PDO library instead, and rewrite your code using that.

Comment: In addition `$_GET{'page'}` is incorrect syntax. `$_GET` is an array, so uses square brackets, not curly braces.

Comment: `$_PHP_SELF` is also incorrect. Use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` if you really need it. But most of the time (including where you're using it), it can usually be left out completely.

Answer (score 1):

I have cheked last page condition by finding `$total_page` and then comparing `$page == $total_page`. `$left_rec` method is not fit all the time.

```
// $left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit); not always give correct result
        $total_page = ceil($rec_count/$rec_limit);
```

`ceil()` is a php function which returns the next highest `integer` value by rounding up. for more info read http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Also you have spaces in your query string thats why you can't get page value  and you need not to use `$_PHP_SELF` you can simply write

```
 echo "<a href = '?page=$page'>Next 10 Records</a>"; or  echo "<a href = 'index.php?page=$page'>Next 10 Records</a>"; if the code is in index.php
```

//  use full code this

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Paging Using PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
     $dbhost = 'localhost';
     $dbuser = 'root';
     $dbpass = 'root123';
     $rec_limit = 10;
     $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

     if(!$conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }
     mysql_select_db('test_db');

     /* Get total number of records */
     $sql = "SELECT count(cinno) FROM register_data";
     $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

     if(!$retval ) {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
     }
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
    $rec_count = $row[0];

     if(isset($_GET['page'] ) ) {
                $page = $_GET['page'];
        $offset = $rec_limit * ($page - 1);
     }else {
        $page = 1;
        $offset = 0;
     }

        // $left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit); not always give correct result
        $total_page = ceil($rec_count/$rec_limit);
      $sql = "select cinno from register_data LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
     $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

     if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not get data2: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "Cin No :{$row['cinno']}  <br> ";

     }

         if( $page >1 && $page != $total_page) {
            $last = $page - 1;
            $page++;            
            echo "<a href = '?page=$last'>Last 10 Records</a> |";
            echo "<a href = '?page=$page'>Next 10 Records</a>";
         }else if( $page == 1 ) {
             $page++;
            echo "<a href = '?page=$page'>Next 10 Records</a>";
         }elseif($page == $total_page){
              $last = $page - 1;
              echo "<a href = '?page=$last'>Last 10 Records</a>";
             }



     mysql_close($conn);
    ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

**Also please use mysqli or PDO(more secure);**

Comment: @adesh singh Try this and let me know it works or not

Answer (score 0):

`$_PHP_SELF` sounds incorrect; you should use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` or in in strings `${_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}`